# opencv_videoio_ffmpeg411.dll (and others) missing after installing a package

Tags: c#

I installed the "OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win" package.

After installing it from Nuget, I have 3 errors:

> Impossible to copy the file "C:\Users\Zonedetec\source\repos\Mes POTG Overwatch\packages\OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU.4.0.0.20181129\runtimes\win-x86\native\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg411.dll", because it cannot be found.
>
> Impossible to copy the file "C:\Users\Zonedetec\source\repos\Mes POTG Overwatch\packages\OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU.4.0.0.20181129\runtimes\win-x86\native\OpenCvSharpExtern.dll",  because it cannot be found.
>
> Impossible to copy the file "C:\Users\Zonedetec\source\repos\Mes POTG Overwatch\packages\OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU.4.0.0.20181129\runtimes\win-x64\native\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg411_64.dll", because it cannot be found
>
> Impossible to copy the file  "C:\Users\Zonedetec\source\repos\Mes POTG Overwatch\packages\OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU.4.0.0.20181129\runtimes\win-x64\native\OpenCvSharpExtern.dll", because it cannot be found

What should I do? (I couldn't find the DLLs online.)

Comment: This is a good question, Please learn the error message first and describe the technical problem indicated by the error in a clear sentence to make the question more clearer and informative.

Answer (score 0):

Native binding (OpenCvSharpExtern.dll / libOpenCvSharpExtern.so) is required to work to OpenCvSharp. To use OpenCvSharp, you should add both `OpenCvSharp4` and `OpenCvSharp4.runtime.*` packages to your project.

Comment: I already have this package installed, they both have the same version.

Comment: you can try `OpenCvSharp4.runtime.Windows` instead of `.win`

Comment: If you're still missing them, you can download them directly from the release page as well https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/releases